# Max Primary Key number before slowing down the queries?

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I'm working with SQLite for the first time and I was wondering if there was a `max primary key id` I should be looking out for before which I should wipe my table? i.e. max should be 1000 at which point, I should copy all data to a separate `history` table to maintain performance when running queries on my `primary table`.

Comment: There are many variables at work here. Optimise when you have some empirical data to work from.

Comment: With proper indexing you can have millions of records in your table without performance loss

Comment: @juergend are you sure? :O I'm pretty sure querying through 1 table with thousands of rows compared to one with millions would be a lot faster.

Comment: @Dilisqq: How do you think google handles quering billions of records in milliseconds? Not by having a billion tables.

Comment: @juergend was that rhetorical? I'd imagine they'd have a couple thousand tables or something and run a query on each :)

Comment: @Dilisqq: Sure they have not just a single table. But with partitioning an indexing you can handle really big data. and 1000 records is for a DB like nothing - a joke.

Comment: @juergend oooh cool. I never knew haha thanks for the heads up! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum INTEGER value is 9223372036854775807 I believe. You'd be more pressed to worry about row count. There's no solid answer for your question, as it would depend on many things. How much data is there per row? Is this an embedded implementation? Run some tests in a relevant environment to see when it starts to chug. That will be a better answer than I could provide.

Comment: Oh okay, good to know! I've got 14 columns so I hope that's okay haha. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: `bigint` is that big. Normal `int` much smaller.

Comment: That doesn't matter in SQLite.